# How do you apply $u$-substitution to the integral $\int v\sqrt{2v^2+1}\,dv$?

Tags: calculus, integration

When doing $u$-substitution of the following integral problem, does the $v$ disappear because it has a value of $1$?

$$\int v\sqrt{2v^2+1}\,dv$$

Comment: I suspect that you’re asking about calculating $\int v\sqrt{2v^2+1}\,dv$ by the substitution $u=2v^2+1$, but you really should say so explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

If $u = 2v^2 + 1$, then $du = 4v\,dv \iff  \color{red}{\frac 14du = v\,dv}$

That gives you the integral $$\int \color{red}{v}\sqrt{2v^2+1}\,\color{red}{dv} = \color{red}{\frac 14}\int \sqrt u \,\color{red}{du}$$

Comment: ok. when finding u. why just use the value under the square root? is this a rule when having a square root?

Comment: It simply makes sense here, greatly simplifying the integral. After all, integrating $\sqrt u = u^{1/2}$ is very straightforward. Sometimes $u$ will be a function under a square root sign, other times, perhaps $u$ will be the denominator of a rational function, or the argument of a logarithm, (the possibilities are endless)...the goal is to simplify the integration. You develop the intuition with practice.

Comment: @everlast: One of the integral rules you know is how to antidifferentiate $\sqrt{x}$; you're hoping to use that knowledge to solve this integral. You make the substitution $u = 2v^2 + 1$ in hopes that after converting that part of the integrand into $\sqrt{u}$, the whole thing will become manageable. You might have tried $\sqrt{2v^2 + 1} = u$ or $2v^2 + 1 = e^u$ or $\sqrt{2v^2 + 1} = \tan(u)$ any number of other things as well, although only the first of these examples would be "natural" to try.

Comment: Clear and simple (+1). @everlast To finish, note that $\int\sqrt u\mathrm du=\frac23u^{3/2}+C$ and substitute $u=2v^2+1$, you get the anti-derivative: $\frac16(2v^2+1)^{3/2}+C$.

Answer (score 1):

No, the $v$ is absorbed into $du$.  If $u=2v^2 +1$, then $du = 4v\,dv$

Comment: so when finding u, what happens to v? I know du is 4v

Comment: @everlast: it becomes part of the differential $du$.  That's the goal of substitution, to simplify the integrand

Comment: @everlast: $du$ is *not* $4v$. $du$ is $4v \, dv$.